# Google Calendar with Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to automtically add calendar entries to Google Calendar from within my Rails App. I am not able to find a gem which allows transparent integration to Gcal.
Problem with gdata - http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html#AccessingFeeds is that its not maintained and it requires the user to go to authentication URL. I am reluctant to store user passwords to everytime authenticate them before posting to their calendar. I already have google based openid using omniauth.
I am looking for a solution which can : 1. Allow updates to user's google calendar. 2. Wont need the user to authenticate everytime they want to update their calendar.